# JNDI @Resource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I have a Java EE application with WildFly, and I use:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/queue/MyQueue")
```

but now I am migrating part of this application to Spring one, and I have no idea how to look up for my JNDI resource.

In `application.yaml` I added:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jndi-name: "java:jms/queue/MyQueue"
```

but it throws an error during startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRoute': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'java:/jms/queue/MyQueue' defined in JNDI environment: JNDI lookup failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
```

MyRoute.java:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/queue/MyQueue")
private Queue queue1;
```

Is it possible to easily inject the resource in Spring?
I wish it can work like `@Autowired` does. Inject the Queue with lookup into JNDI.

Comment: You can inject it with `@Autowired`, you just need to define a corresponding `@Bean`. Define your bean either in XML or by adding `@Component` (or corresponding annotation) on top of your resource.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri can you give me an example?

Comment: A `java.sql.DataSource` is no way close to an `javax.jms.Queue` so that will obviously fail. Use a `JndiTemplate` to lookup the queue and make it available as a bean. Or just leave the `@Resource` as spring can use that as well.